# How do I read temperature, humidity, and pressure values from Bluetooth low energy sensors using Python?

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

I am working on a BLE client that reads temperature, humidity, and pressure from a TE MS8607 I2C sensor attached to an ESP32C3 DevKit.  I am using BleakClient,Python 3.9, and Asyncio.  I defined a routine that reads the characteristic values from the ESP32 and prints them to the serial monitor.  That works. I now want to plot repeated readings of the returned values but so far cannot seem to move the variables that I printed out to main where I attach the data to array to plot. I tried to create the tout in first lines of the program and then used tout in my get_THP but that tout does not get updated in my main.  Instead I just see the initialization value.  The following are some code snippets.  I have tried several ways of doing return values with suggestions like console.log(await get_THP()) but that does seem to work for me.

```
async def get_THP():
    client = BleakClient(address)
    try:
        await client.connect()
        TempC = await client.read_gatt_char(tempC_UUID)
        humidity = await client.read_gatt_char(humidity_UUID)
        pressure = await client.read_gatt_char(pressure_UUID)
        encoding='utf-8'
        tc = TempC.decode(encoding)
        tout=float(tc)
        h=humidity.decode(encoding)
        hout=float(h)
        p = pressure.decode(encoding)
        pout=float(p)
        print("%.1f degC"%tout)
        #...RETURNS THP VALUES TO MONITOR.

async def main(address):
    count=1
    maxpoints=3
    t1=datetime.datetime.now()
    interval=1
      
    while(1):
        
        print(count)
        await  get_THP()
        print(tout)
        #..DOES NOT GET THE VALUES
```

print(tout) in getData returns the correct value but in main returns the initial 0 value. How do I #get the returned values back into my main program?

hoping to transfer the temperature, humidity and pressure return readings from the ESP32 server into variables that I can append to previous readings and then plot the values over time.  I do have plotting and asyncio.sleep delays on looping get_THP() working.  I only use DateTime to get the current time for a measurement.

Comment: You don't seem to have a `return` statement in your `get_THP` function. You might want to take a look at: https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#understanding-the-python-return-statement . You should also look at the section on that page `Returning vs Printing` values

Comment: uKBaz you are correct.  The current version added to the last line of the Get_THP() try: a  return(tout,hout, pout) line.  I also found I needed to initialize and create the tout,pout, and hout variables inside of the main function with the VS Studio compiler that I was using.  The variables did not seem to pass from a global definition into the async main  but I did not confirm. Still learning python details... Thanks for looking at code.

Answer (score 0):

I had several issues understanding async.  Most of the problems were solved with "async for" and a asyncio definition for iterations.  The original code tried to retrieve data inside of a while loop which fails.  The new approach recovers the BLE data from an "async for" loop with async iterations.  This code solved the retrieval problem.

```
async def iterations(loops):
    for i in range(loops):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def main(address):
    tout=0
    pout=0
    hout=0
    ipause=10
    loops=12 # total time of run is ipause*loops = approx 120 seconds
    tv=[]
    hv=[]
    pv=[]
    xtimes=[]
    
    async for i in iterations(loops):
        (tout,hout,pout)=await get_THP()
        await say_after(ipause,"waited ipause seconds")
        tv=np.append(tout,tv)
        hv=np.append(hout,hv)
        pv=np.append(pout,pv)
        xtimes=np.append((mdates.date2num(dt.datetime.now())),xtimes)
        print(i*ipause)
       

    plot(tv,hv,pv,xtimes)
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main(address))
```